# Dynamically pass required fields into GraphQL query

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, graphql-js

I have a query where my required fields inside the query may change. User is allowed to generate the query on fly and user can select the fields in the query. Is there a way to pass the required fields into query based on user's selection from a dropdown. Eg: in below query id, traveller, visaApplication can be replaced by anyother fields. So my queries has to dynamic.

```
{
    Travels{
      id
      traveller {
        nationality
        firstName
      }
      visaApplication {
        nationality
        city
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fields can be added dynamically using string interpolation:

```
const otherFields = `
  traveller {
    nationality
    firstName
  }
`
const query = gql`
  {
    Travels {
      id
      ${otherFields}
    }
  }
`
```

You can also utilize the `@skip` or `@include` directives, combined with variables, to control whether to skip/include particular fields for a specific request while utilizing a single query:

```
const query = gql`
  query (
    $includeTraveller: Boolean!
    $includeVisa: Boolean!
  ) {
    Travels {
      id
      traveller @include(if: $includeTraveller) {
        nationality
        firstName
      }
      visaApplication @include(if: $includeVisa) {
        nationality
        city
      }
    }
  }
`
```